# Flutter otp not working while sending an OTP in mobile phone

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, one-time-password

I am trying to send otp using Flutter OTP https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_otp. And I am not looking forward to sending OTP with Firebase Auth. When a user passes a phone number through my app I want to send an OTP and verify it back. But I came across this Flutter_otp where it does not require firebase and its dependencies are https://pub.dev/packages/sms and flutter only. Here is the code snippet where I wanted to test if the OTP is sent or not.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_otp/flutter_otp.dart';

class MyAppextends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  const MyPailaApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController();
  FlutterOtp otpsender = new FlutterOtp();

  @override
  void dispose() {
     super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
      child: TextField(
          cursorColor: Colors.black,
          controller: _controller,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Tap to type',
            suffixIcon: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.send, color: Colors.black,),
              onPressed: (){
                setState(() {
                  otpsender.sendOtp(_controller.text, 'OTP is : pass the generated otp here ',
                        100000, 999999, '+977');
                  _controller.clear();
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But after clicking the Icon in the text field, I am getting the following error and the OTP is not sent also.

```
Running with unsound null safety
For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57564/Qnt0yPHy_eA=/ws
Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method sendSMS on channel plugins.babariviere.com/sendSMS)
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:58819/dart_sdk.js:5348:11)
    at MethodChannel._invokeMethod (http://localhost:58819/packages/flutter/src/services/system_channels.dart.lib.js:962:21)
    at _invokeMethod.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:58819/dart_sdk.js:39230:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:58819/dart_sdk.js:39087:58)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:58819/dart_sdk.js:34073:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:58819/dart_sdk.js:34633:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:58819/dart_sdk.js:34671:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:58819/dart_sdk.js:34513:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:58819/dart_sdk.js:34536:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:58819/dart_sdk.js:39374:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:58819/dart_sdk.js:39380:13)
    at http://localhost:58819/dart_sdk.js:34887:9

======== Exception caught by services library ======================================================
The following MissingPluginException was thrown while activating platform stream on channel plugins.babariviere.com/statusSMS:
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method listen on channel plugins.babariviere.com/statusSMS)

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 236:49  throw_
packages/flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart 156:7                                                                  _invokeMethod
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50            <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1613:54                                          runUnary
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 155:18                                    handleValue
...
====================================================================================================
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: What platform are you running this code on?

Comment: Currently, for testing, I am running it on Web.

Comment: If the answer below helped you, consider marking it as the accepted answer, so we can help others with the same question

Answer (score 0):

**The packages you are using are not supported on Web.**

*The same should work on Android and iOS only.*

The error message `MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method listen on channel plugins.babariviere.com/statusSMS)` is trying to communicate that.

All plugins on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev) display their supported platforms as we can see, both the plugins you want to use are not supported on Web, but only iOS and Android

[image]
[image]